# Get upload progress with AWS S3 signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I'm making an application that let user to upload their video to our end using AWS S3. I use a server to generate signed url and return it to client(web browser), then client uses that url to upload to our backend. It works pretty well, but I have a small problem that we can't keep track the progress of file upload which started from browser.

So are there any ways we can get progress of the uploads from our server?

Comment: What is the process of performing the upload from the client-side?

Comment: The process is just normal file upload to the signed url that generated from server. As I know, I can get progress from browser which do the uploading. But I need get it from server for my admin panel.

Answer (score -1):

Java Snippet for the Same

```
public void uploadtoS3(File file) throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException, InterruptedException {
        logger.debug("Uploading the File => S3");
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialProviderChain = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
        TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(credentialProviderChain.getCredentials());
        final Upload upload = tx.upload(env.getProperty("amazon.s3.media.bucket"), file.getName(), file);

        // You can poll your transfer's status to check its progress
        if (upload.isDone() == false) {
            logger.debug("Transfer: " + upload.getDescription());
            logger.debug("State: " + upload.getState());
            logger.debug("Progress: " + upload.getProgress().getBytesTransferred());
        }

        // Transfers also allow you to set a <code>ProgressListener</code> to
        // receive
        // asynchronous notifications about your transfer's progress.

        upload.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            // This method is called periodically as your transfer progresses
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                logger.debug(upload.getProgress().getPercentTransferred() + "%");

                if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    logger.debug("Upload complete!!!");
                }
            }
        });

        // Or you can block the current thread and wait for your transfer to
        // to complete. If the transfer fails, this method will throw an
        // AmazonClientException or AmazonServiceException detailing the reason.
        upload.waitForCompletion();

        // After the upload is complete, call shutdownNow to release the
        // resources.
        tx.shutdownNow();
    }
```

Also works with the MultiPart uploads.